# Using JetBrains DataGrip - where do I find Functions?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I just created a function, but I cannot find it in the schema. To make sure that I was reading the latest schema I even restarted DataGrip.

Where are Functions found in DataGrip?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In **Routines** section of the database tree.

You can also turn on 'Seperate Procedures and Functions' to see them in different folders.

[image]

Comment: Note that I'm pretty sure you need to have created a function in order to see the `routines` folder. I had no functions & couldn't find it, but upon creating one in the console, the folder appeared immediately.

Comment: To see the empty folder turn on Show Empty Groups: https://ibb.co/dDr5K6

Comment: I see my triggers, but not my functions

Comment: Please, share a screenshot